# Reflecting Angles in the Y Axis

Tags: math, trigonometry, angle

I'm currently to reflect an angle in the Y axis using 'Pi - angle'. The angle system I'm using is in radians, with 0 being east, -Pi/2 being north, Pi/2 being south and +/- Pi being west and when I try using the above method to reflect an angle, it frequently returns values above Pi, outside the range. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection about the x-axis: just use `-angle`.

Reflection about the y-axis: use

```
   if (angle >= 0)
      return pi - angle
   else
      return -pi - angle
```

This creates a branch cut at 0: 3° maps to 177°, whereas -3° maps to -177°. 0 maps to pi. (If you require angles in the [-pi,pi) interval that excludes +pi, change the ">=" to ">".

This also assumes that the input angle is within the [-pi,pi] range, as your problem statement suggests. If not, you need to normalize using a symmetric modulo 2*pi (where `smod(x,M) = mod(x+M/2,M) - M/2`) first.

Comment: before you guys upvote, check my math ;-) earlier edits were incorrect

Comment: Technically correct if the input and output angles are normalized to be between -pi and +pi. Otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

By first having your initial angle modulo-divided by Pi. So, in C language:

```
angle = fmod(angle, 2*Pi);
if (angle < -Pi)
    angle = angle + 2*Pi;

float inverted = Pi - angle;
```

The thing is to always normalize your input before further processing.

Comment: Incorrect. You need to consider angles modulo 2*pi, not modulo pi.

Comment: I did, but you might want to remove the "C language" bit, since "%" is an integer modulo operator, not a floating-point operator; use fmod() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since full circle is 2*pi, you ca always subtract 2*pi and have the angle back in range.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth whould you choose north to be -Pi/2. It breaks all default stuf like sin(angle) = y coordinate on the unit circle.

But to answer your question you can add k*2Pi to all your angles (where k is any integer number) and the angle will stay the same.

Comment: North is -Pi/2 because the co-ordinates system I'm using places (0,0) in the top left and angles are measured relative to the x axis. It's the default angle system returned by atan2.